# Stopping several Media Players in android

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I have several MediaPlayers in the same activity. It works this way:

MediaPlayer mpOne starts playing, if a variable has a value "yes" MediaPlayer mptwo starts playing, else mpThree starts.
When the audio ends, starts another process identical
This is my code:

```
MediaPlayer mpOne,mpTwo,mpThree,mpFour,mpFive

...
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        setContentView(R.layout.morning);

        mpOne= MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.one);
        mphora.setLooping(false);
mpTwo= MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.two);
        mphora.setLooping(false);
mpThree= MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.three);
        mphora.setLooping(false);
mpFour= MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.four);
        mphora.setLooping(false);
mpFive= MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.five);
        mphora.setLooping(false);

    mpOne.start();
        mpOne.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) 
            {
                if (variable.equals("yes"){
                        mpTwo.start();
            } else {
            mpThree.start();    
            }
        });

        mpTwo.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) 
            {
            mpFour.start();
        });

        mpThree.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) 
            {
            mpFour.start();
        });

        mpFour.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) 
            {
            // same proccess
        });

}
```

My problem is when I want to stop all audios.
Currently I have a button that does the following:

```
stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){ 
                public void onClick(View view){ 

.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){ 
                public void onClick(View view){ 

                    if(mpOne.isPlaying()){mpOne.stop();mpOne.release();}
                    else if(mpTwo.isPlaying()){mpTwo.stop();mpTwo.release();}
                    else if(mpThree.isPlaying()){mpThree.stop();mpThree.release();}
                    else if(mpFour.isPlaying()){mpFour.stop();mpFour.release();}
                    else if(mpFive.isPlaying()){mpFive.stop();mpFive.release();}
                }
                }
        });
```

The problem is that sometimes it works and sometimes the audio still playing.

I've searched and found similar problems, but not a solution

Can anyone tell me a safe way to stop all playback?

Thank you very much in advance.

regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do only one MediaPlayer instance and at onCompletion setting a different audio source

Comment: but to start a new audio source, must launch a new MediaPlayer, no?
I think that i do not understand your answer.
You have an example, please? Thanks

Comment: @MiguelC Paolino is correct. Each time you want to play a new sound (I'm assuming it's sound), you should go through the `reset()`, `setDataSource(...)`, `prepare()`, `start()` sequence on the same `MediaPlayer`. Or at most, alternate between two. If the sounds are short, you should probably look into `SoundPool` also. It may be more appropriate for your situation.